# URLConnection dont work on linux

Tags: linux, urlconnection, inputstreamreader

i have a big Problem at the moment and i hope anybody know a fix.

on my server i use this code to check vote counts on a website:

```
    @Override
public int getVoteCount()
{
    int votes = 0;
    try
    {
        URL oracle = new URL(getLinkToCheck());
        URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            if (inputLine.contains("<div class='list_8' style=\"font-weight: bold\">"))
            {
                String line = inputLine.split("<div class='list_8' style=\"font-weight: bold\">")[1].split("</div>")[0].trim().replaceAll(" ", "");
                votes = Integer.parseInt(line);
                if (VoteManager.VOTE_DEBUG)
                {
                    System.out.println("VoteManager [" + getClass().getSimpleName() + "]: Votes count: [" + votes + "]");
                }
                return votes;
            }
        }
        in.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return votes;
}
```

Comment: So, what's the "big problem" you're experiencing? We need more to go on.

Comment: i get no response. he get no input.